# Bringing Alcohol back from Germany when under 21

Tags: germany, alcohol

Can my sister under age 21 bring me back alcohol to the United States from Germany when she returns? Would there be any issue? What if I met her at the gate?

Comment: Yes there will be an issue. If your parents meet her at the airport she *may* be escorted out to meet them (a customs officer will carry the alcohol.) Or it may be confiscated. There is another similar question on this site -- I'll see if I can track it down.

Comment: Here's one: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/112872/can-a-twenty-year-old-bring-to-the-usa-alcohol-purchased-legally-in-spain

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not legally possible. From [Bringing alcohol (including homemade wine) to the U.S. for personal use](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/190/~/bringing-alcohol-%28including-homemade-wine%29-to-the-u.s.-for-personal-use):

> It is illegal for travelers under the age of 21 to import alcohol - even as a gift.

You cannot meet her "at the gate" because she must pass through customs (where she must declare the alcohol) before she has an opportunity to meet you.